# Prevent a light from shining on an object three.js ; LAYERS

Tags: three.js

I am trying to make light1 shine on object1 (both on layer 0) and light2 shine on object2 (both on layer 1) only. I am trying to use layers. The moment I put a camera on both layers however (layer 0 and 1). The lights clearly affect objects from both layers.

I have used a workaround from [Three.js - How to prevent a light from shining on an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586385/three-js-how-to-prevent-a-light-from-shining-on-an-object)

but still it feels like there should be a nice solution with layers... that's what they are for right?

Thank you!

```
var ambientLight = getAmbientLight(2);
var pointLight = getPointLight(0.5);

function getAmbientLight(intensity) {
var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, intensity);

return light;
}

function getPointLight(intensity) {
var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, intensity);
//light.castShadow = true;
light.layers.set(1);
return light;
}


var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
            loader.load( 'models/scene.gltf', function ( gltf ) {

            console.log(gltf.scene);

                gltf.scene.traverse( function ( child ) {
                    if ( child.isMesh ) {
                        child.layers.set(0);
                        console.log(child);
                    }
                } ); 
                scene.add( gltf.scene ); 
            }, undefined, function ( e ) {
                console.error( e );
            } );

var sphere = getSphere (0.4, 10, 10);

function getSphere(r) {
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(r, 24, 24);

var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {
    color: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
    //side: THREE.DoubleSide
    } );

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( 
    geometry, 
    material );
mesh.layers.set(1); 
    return mesh; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the documentation (https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Layers), layers are intended to control the visibility of objects. So an object is only rendered if it shares a common layer with the given camera. Layers can't be used right now to determine which objects should be affected from which light sources (also known as selective lighting). Please use the mentioned workaround for this. Besides, read the following github issue for more information about the topic:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5180

`three.js R96`